# Rhino Mocks calls real method in Arrange

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I am trying to stub a method call of a class like this:

Manager managerStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub(constructordata);
managerStub.Stub(x => x.GetData(Arg.Is.Anything)).Return(10)

But when I try to run this unit test, Rhino mocks calls the "GetData" method, with parameter "0"  on the "manager.Stub..." line.

Why does Rhino Mocks call the real method?

Comment: Is the real method `virtual`? If not, RhinoMocks can't stub it.

Comment: Ah... it isn't. That was the problem, post an answer, I will accept it, when the time limit ends.

Comment: Added an answer with details why it needs to be virtual.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you request a stub of a class RhinoMocks creates a derived class on the fly and overrides the methods you want to stub.
However, if the method you want to stub is not `virtual` RhinoMocks can't override it and thus it can't stub it.